# Using the merge sort algorithm to order a list of strings by string length from the longest to the shortest string

Tags: python

I already have a bit of code, but it only works on a list of integers, i need to modify it to sort a list of strings according to the length of each string in the list, i know i have to include a for loop to iterate through the list and get the length of each string that way, but i cant put it in code.

```
def merge_sort(items):
        
    n = len(items)
    temporary_storage = [None] * n
    size_of_subsections = 1
    
    while size_of_subsections < n:
        for i in range(0, n ,size_of_subsections * 2):
            l1_start, l1_end = i, min(i + size_of_subsections, n)
            l2_start, l2_end = l1_end, min(l1_end + size_of_subsections, n)
            sections = (l1_start, l1_end), (l2_start, l2_end)
            merge(items, sections, temporary_storage)
        
        size_of_subsections *= 2
            
    return items


def merge(items, sections, tempory_storage):
    (start_1, end_1), (start_2, end_2) = sections
    i_1 = start_1
    i_2 = start_2
    i_t = 0
    
    while i_1 < end_1 or i_2 < end_2:
        if i_1 < end_1 and i_2 < end_2:
            if items[i_1] < items[i_2]:
                tempory_storage[i_t] = items[i_1]
                i_1 += 1
            else:
                tempory_storage[i_t] = items[i_2]
                i_2 += 1
            i_t += 1
            
        elif i_1 < end_1:
            for i in range(i_1, end_1):
                tempory_storage[i_t] = items[i_1]
                i_1 += 1
                i_t += 1
                
        else:
            for i in range(i_2, end_2):
                tempory_storage[i_t] = items[i_2]
                i_2 += 1
                i_t += 1
                
    for i in range(i_t):
        items[start_1 + 1] = tempory_storage[i]
        
    return()
```

This is what i have so far, but only works for a list of integers.

Comment: if there is a better way of doing it, please i would really appreciate the help

Answer (score -1):

To sort a list of strings based on string length I propose the following method:

```
def merge_sort(items):
    # 1. create a list of tuples (string-length,index)
    sort_list=[(len(item),i) for i,item in enumerate(items)]
    # 2. sort the list based on the length (list of tuples will be sorted by the first element in the tuple)
    sort_list.sort()
    # create the result by taken out the indexes from sorted list
    return [items[i] for s,i in sort_list]
```

Here is the example of the usage:

```
>>> test_list=['123456789','123','12345','123']
>>> print(merge_sort(test_list))
['123', '123', '12345', '123456789']
```

Maybe I misunderstood but I hope this helps. To get longest to shortest you might reverse the resulting list.

For large list I recommend the same solution based on `numpy` functions (without loops).

Comment: Python's built-in `sort` and `sorted` use [Timsort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which is a hybrid of merge and insertion sort. The point of OP's exercise is likely to learn about merge sort, so an answer that says "use the built-in" isn't helpful.

Comment: Also, if you're using the built-in anyway, `sorted(items, key=len)` does the job. The difference between that and your code is that yours sorts elements with equal length, while `sorted(...)` maintains the original order

Comment: I got the point, but as I said maybe I missunderstood. But maybe an example in the description of the input and output might be helpful.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the example, would this work if the elements in the list are words as well?

Comment: What do you mean with words? It should work for any string. 

But I agree with @PranavHosangadi if you really need just a solution use the buildin `sorted()`. 
The line: `sorted(test_list,key=len,reverse=True)` does exactly what you need.